# Sharepoint Document Library -- Document Set

Tags: sharepoint

How do I save a folder hierarchy in document library in sharepoint server 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are trying to do this via code or via the user interface. When using the User Interface the easiest thing to do is to click the '[Open in Windows Explorer](http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1032)' option in a document library and drag and drop the folders you need to copy.